# GcmTaskService: cancelling and scheduling a tag for a task which is currently processing

Tags: java, android, multithreading, gcm-network-manager, gcmtaskservice

With `GcmNetworkManager`, my understanding is two tasks with same tag can never run concurrently. This is according to documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmTaskService)

> Per service, two tasks with the same tag will never execute
>   concurrently. Should a newly-scheduled task arrive while an existing
>   task is still running, the new task will be dropped. In addition,
>   different tasks may be scheduled concurrently, each invoked in a
>   separate thread, if their schedules overlap. It is up to you to ensure
>   thread safety when scheduling multiple tasks.

My question is:

If we schedule a task (a `OneoffTask`):

```
Task myTask = ... ;// create task of MY_TAG
gcmNetworkManager.schedule(myTask);
```

Then at some point later on we cancel it but let's assume it's currently running (its `GcmTaskService:onRunTask` is still running on its thread):

```
// Cancel task
// At this point GcmTaskService:onServiceRun could still be running (on a different thread)! 
// `GcmTaskService:onRunTask` will continue to run
gcmNetworkManager.cancelTask(MY_TAG, ..);
```

and then at another time later on, we re-schedule same tag:

```
// Re-schedule task. 
// At this point GcmTaskService:onRunTask could still be running (on a different thread)! 
Task myTask = ... ;// create task of MY_TAG
gcmNetworkManager.schedule(myTask);
```

when time comes to run `GcmTaskService:onRunTask` for the re-scheduled task, does `GcmNetworkManager` still knows there is a task running (`GcmTaskService::onRunTask()` hasn't returned? (Note that at this point its tag was cancelled)

Or does it actually starts a new `GcmTaskService` and call`GcmTakService:onRunTask` because its tag was cancelled? 
Which means there could actually be two `GcmTaskService:onRunTask` running at same time for same tag.